# WiX: Adding summary dialog displaying installed features

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to display to the users a summary page at the end of the installation that shows what features were installed.  The ADDLOCAL property contains this information, but I cannot figure out how to display its value on a dialog.  Adding it as the Text property of a Control does not work.

```
<!-- Does not display anything -->
<Control Id="InstalledFeaturesText" Type="Text" ... Text="[ADDLOCAL]" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: To do the similar thing I created the whole dialog, copying code of the existing dialog from WiX SDK, and in it I added one text control. I don't know if that is the proper way, though.

Comment: That is what I have done as well.  However, the text control is blank - as if "ADDLOCAL" does not have a value set.  When I look at the msiexec log, though, it shows 'Property(s): ADDLOCAL=Feature1,Feature2,Feature3'.  If I try using a different built-in property like USERNAME, it works as expected.  There must be a way to access the list of features to be installed, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you check the verbose log of your installation - find property change events for ADDLOCAL property. Maybe it get's reassigned to empty string at some point. YOu can save the value of that property into your custom property which works find as you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to your wix source code

```
<SetProperty Id="FEATURELIST" Value="[ADDLOCAL]" After="CostFinalize"/>
```

And use `FEATURELIST` property to get list of all installed feture.
That’s really it. :)

This is so because it appears that the `'ADDLOCAL`' becomes undefined after completion of all install sequence.